# How to split dataframes in 2 dataframes based on a nullable column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]so I have a dataframe and I tried this:

```
filteredBillCancelledDate_df = df[df['sdBillCancelledDate'].notnull()]
```

however when I check the dataframe, I still see NULL rows there, so filtering is not really working

Comment: missing values are in column `sdBillCancelledDate` ? Or in another columns?

Comment: yes in that one

Comment: You need test it after converting to datetimes, then working well.

Comment: after I convert them the NULL are converted to NaT, how do I filter those out?

Comment: It working like `NaN`, it means misisng values for datetimes. So your solution from this question working well.

Comment: string literal "NULL" is not the same as `isna()` / `isnull()`.  Values of None / NaN will be what you need for filter to work.  If you really want string literals then it would be` != "NULL"`

Comment: what about if I want to filter on NaT (after I converted to datetime)?